# Using JS for multi-page mobile site

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I'm building a large site (30+ pages) and wanting to use a centralized HTML page with 3 columns. I'd like the middle column to change depending on links clicked either via the left column (nav side bar) or a nav at the top of the page.

Here's a simple layout out of what I'm talking about (don't know why the middle section isn't going behind the left-panel though). https://jsfiddle.net/cxLcmfh8/

So, different `.middle-panel` objects are linked to a `.left-panel` nav element. The left nav would remain the same and the middle would fade in depending on which link is clicked.

I'm worried something like this would be too large for mobile users. Is there a way to build a large site with a setup like this without having to have mobile users basically download the entire site just to enjoy some neat transitions?

Comment: I'm not understanding your question but it seems like it the question doesn't have to do with code. Perhaps programmers.SE, graphicdesign.SE, or maybe UX.SE

Comment: @vihan1086 when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: Agreed @gnat - Could you point me in the direction of said previously posted question as I was unable to find it - hence my post, poorly explained.

Answer (score 0):

if data is not to large that wont create any difference if large than you should use server side scripting `like PHP,JSP or servlet` to generate response in same page and apply animation when page load.

or use AJAX to download data as and when required and apply transition. This method would not download all data and won't create over head it take time depending on net speed.